# Como puedo copiar un valor en google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un problema al copiar un valor de una celda a otra en google app script y google sheet. Necesito poner el valor de una celda en otra.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheetcoil = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = 'prueba'
  var datos = sheetcoil.getSheetByName(sheet1);
  var coil = datos.getRange(1,1)
  Logger.log(coil.getValue())
  var coil1 = datos.getRange(2,2).getValue(coil)
}
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> Exception: Los parámetros (SpreadsheetApp.Range) no coinciden con la firma de método de SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue. (línea 7, archivo "Código")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pareciera que estás utilizando el método equivocado (y  el valor equivocado también).

En la línea 7 se está llamando `datos.getRange(2,2).getValue(coil)` sin embargo, para modificar el valor del `Range` deberías hacer uso de [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue).
Acorde a la documentación este valor debe ser un "string, numérico, booleano o fecha" en este caso sospecho que quisieras `coil.getValue()`. Al final el código se debería de ver así:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheetcoil = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = 'prueba';
  var datos = sheetcoil.getSheetByName(sheet1);
  var coil = datos.getRange(1,1);
  Logger.log(coil.getValue());
  var coil1 = datos.getRange(2,2).setValue(coil.getValue());
}
```